# Twitter OAuth, Error when trying to POST direct message

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

So I am building a java script that is used in conjunction of my C++ application for sending direct messages to users. the script does the work of building the request that i send. When i send a request i receive "Incorrect signature" or "can not authenticate you" Does anyone see something i am missing or am doing wrong? I am continuing to investigate. Thank you in advance

Javascript:

```
var nDate = new Date();
var epoch = nDate.getTime();
var nounce = "";

nounce = Base64.encode(epoch+randomString()); 

var Parameters =   [
   "oauth_consumerkey="+sConsumerKey,
   "oauth_nonce="+nounce,
   "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1",
   "oauth_timestamp="+epoch,
   "oauth_token="+sAccessToken,
   "oauth_version=1.0",
   "text="+sText,
   "user="+sUser];

var SortedParameters = Parameters.sort(); 
var joinParameters = SortedParameters.join("&");
var encodeParameters = escape(joinParameters);



signature_base_string = escape("POST&"+NormalizedURL+"&"+encodeParameters);

signature_key = sConsumerSecret+"&"+sAccessSecret;

signature = Base64.encode(hmacsha1(signature_base_string,signature_key));


sAuthHeader = "
  OAuth realm=, 
  oauth_nonce="+nounce+",
  oauth_timestamp="+epoch+",     
  oauth_consumer_key="+sConsumerKey+",
  oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, 
  oauth_version=1.0,
  oauth_signature="+signature+",
  oauth_token="+sAccessToken+",
  text="+sText;

goNVOut.Set("Header.Authorization: ", sAuthHeader);
```

Comment: One thing to check is to make sure your servers time is synced with Twitter's. If it is more then 5 minutes off your requests will fail.

Comment: how can I get Twitter's time?

Comment: I have been slowly getting it, its not the completely working but, when you call Java scripts get time I was pulling epoch time in milliseconds. thanks Abraham!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple things to be careful about:

- JavaScript's "escape" function will not work for OAuth URL encoding, as per the [OAuth Spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#encoding_parameters).

> 5.1.  Parameter Encoding
>
> All parameter names and values are
>   escaped using the [RFC3986]
>   percent-encoding (%xx) mechanism.
>   Characters not in the unreserved
>   character set ([RFC3986] section 2.3)
>   MUST be encoded. Characters in the
>   unreserved character set MUST NOT be
>   encoded. Hexadecimal characters in
>   encodings MUST be upper case. Text
>   names and values MUST be encoded as
>   UTF-8 octets before percent-encoding
>   them per [RFC3629].
>
> ```
>         unreserved = ALPHA, DIGIT, '-', '.', '_', '~'
> ```

JavaScript's escape function will let @ * + / through, unescaped.  I'm confident that that will break the signature signing process, since the server will be escaping those, and the HMAC-SHA1 value it computes will be different than yours.

- Be sure to URL encode your base URI, NormalizedURL, as well.

I found that getting the encoding correct is the most tedious part of OAuth.  Be sure to use upper-case letters in your new "url_encode" function.

Here's my C++ code to do the URL encoding.  It could be optimized a bit but should be easy to understand.

```
char hexdigit(int ch)
{
    assert(ch < 16);
    assert(ch >= 0);
    if (ch >= 10)
        return 'A' + ch - 10;
    return '0' + ch;
}

std::string url_encode(const std::string &to_encode)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (std::string::const_iterator ich = to_encode.begin();
         ich != to_encode.end();
         ++ich)
    {
        unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)*ich;
        if (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ch == '-' || ch == '_' || ch == '.' || ch == '~')
        {
            ss << ch;
        }
        else
        {
            ss << '%';
            ss << hexdigit(ch >> 4);
            ss << hexdigit(ch & 0xf);
        }
    }

    std::string encoded = ss.str();
    return encoded;
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Will, the encoding was getting me into trouble as well. now i am just slowly debugging until the format is what needs to be for Twitter. Thanks you guys!!!

Comment: if u dont want to do anything just do this http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=message