# twitter oauth request_token failed

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

i'm currently developping an application for twitter, using javascript and OAuth, for a qml environment.
I'm stuck in "request_token" endpoint and i don't understand why.
I only get "failed to validate oauth signature or token" when i send my request !
I've checked my signature generation with http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html and http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/ and it does appear that my signature and my basestring are both right !
I've tried to send data in "authorization" http header field, and in body.
Here is my basestring :

> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_consumer_key%3D26oauth_nonce%3DDbWO0M%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1303129797%26oauth_token%3D%26oauth_version%3D1.0

The part i've sent in header field "Authorization" is :

> oauth_consumer_key=&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1303130860&oauth_nonce=UX2kEA&oauth_signature=LizFO9xkre2Kv5A43Oj%2F%2FaY9Wck%3D

If someone can help me with this issue... i've checked every step with OAuth library examples and other tools on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out this answer to a similar issue.  It may contain your solution:
[Twitter OAuth, Error when trying to POST direct message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968502/twitter-oauth-error-when-trying-to-post-direct-message/2982950#2982950)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks !
I've tried to change my url_encoded and it does not change the result. I've deleted my code and begin once again, i'm not using oauth anymore. It appears that my basestring and my signature are right (hope to http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/ and http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html) but i'n still getting the same issue. Maybe it's about the string i'm building, i'm trying another way (still integrating your solution)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that Twitter's implementation of oauth does not need oauth_token to sign the basestring (as said in Twitter's API doc). Further more, you shouldn't write it in your basestring.

Authorization header field should be fill this way :

```
OAuth oauth_nonce="1Rek6K",oauth_callback="oob",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1303375383",oauth_consumer_key="<YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_signature="fgb6sPPR2PHQD%2BinG2KvtvgOtXU%3D",oauth_version="1.0"
```

The mendatory oauth_callback sould be set as "oob" for desktop applications.